# Loop through list elements to get cumulative sums

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, cumulative-sum

I'm very new to python. I'm trying to create a loop so that I can get cumulative sums of the elements in a list. For example, given a list [3, 2, 1] I'm hoping to get [3 (first number), 5 (3+2), 6 (3+2+1)], [2 (second number), 3 (2+1)] and [1].

What I have currently is:

```
data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
for i in data:
    perf = [sum(data[:i+1]) for i in range(len(data))]
    print(perf)
```

And I'm getting the following as output, which is the sum from the first element. How do I modify to get the cumulative sums starting with 4, 3, ... ?

```
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
```

My desired output

```
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[4, 7, 9, 10]
[3, 5, 6]
[2, 3]
[1]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far from the answer. You just need to begin your range from the next num in the list. Try this:

```
data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
for ind, num in enumerate(data):
    perf = [sum(data[ind:i+1]) for i in range(ind, len(data))]
    print(perf)
```

Output:

```
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[4, 7, 9, 10]
[3, 5, 6]
[2, 3]
[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, in the 1. iteration you want to get sums from first element, in the 2. iteration sums from second element and so on:

```py
data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
for i in range(len(data)):
    s = 0
    l = [s := s + d for d in data[i:]]
    print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
[4, 7, 9, 10]
[3, 5, 6]
[2, 3]
[1]
```

---

Or: using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

```py
from itertools import accumulate

data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(list(accumulate(data[i:])))
```

Comment: I've just amended my question to be clearer. But yes you understood me right! Thank you, will try that out!

Answer (score 1):

Your statement to compute a commulative sum within the loop is correct.
You had just used `i` incorrectly in the outer loop statement.

All you need to do is slice your original data and generate sums for each slice.

```py
test_data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

def commulative_sum(a_list: list[int]):
    # The same thing you wrote
    return [sum(a_list[:i+1]) for i in range(len(a_list))]

def commulative_sums(data: list[int]):
    # Slice the input data and generate commulative sums
    return [commulative_sum(data[j:]) for j in range(len(data))]

result = commulative_sums(test_data)
print(result)
```

> [[5, 9, 12, 14, 15], [4, 7, 9, 10], [3, 5, 6], [2, 3], [1]]

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways you can solve this problem.

```
data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

k = 0;
for i in data:
    k = k + i
print(k)
```

And this is the second method

```
data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

k = 0;
for i in range(len(data)):
    k = k + data[i]
print(k)
```